# Automatically installing Python dependencies using CMake

Tags: python, cmake, pip, setuptools

I've had a quick look around, but because of terminology like dependencies and packages being used in different ways, it's quite tricky to pin down an answer.

I'm building a mixed-language source (Fortran, some C and Python) and the Fortran calls a Python script which depends on the `networkx` Python package in the PyPI. Normally, I just have `networkx` installed anyway, so it isn't a problem for me when rebuilding.

However, for distribution, I want the best way to:

- Install `pip` or equivalent, if it is not installed.
- Possibly install `virtualenv` and create a virtual environment, if appropriate.
- Download and install `networkx` using the `--user` option with `pip`.

Is there a standard way? Or should I just use CMake dependencies with custom commands that install `pip` etc.?

Answer (score 0):

it depends. for "manual" install, you definitely should detect if all required (to build) tools are installed, and issue an error if they don't. then use `execute_process()` to run `pip` and whatever you want.
from other side, if you are going to produce a real package for some particular Linux, you just pack your binaries and *require* (via corresponding syntax of particular package format like `*.rpm` or `*.deb` that your package *depends* on some other packages. so, you can be sure that they will be installed w/ (or even before) your package.